# C++. Error handling private member variables in a class that are initialised in a constructor

Tags: class, if-statement, error-handling, conditional-statements

Im learning how to use classes in C++ in university right now. To practice we have been told to make a DateC class that has the private member variables: day, month and year with some other public functions that we need to write to print the date and modify it.

Here's my code so far:

prog.cpp (the main)

```
#include <iostream>
#include "date.h"

//ASK HOW THE CONTENTS OF DATE.CPP ARE ACCESSED IN THIS FILE SEEING AS ITS NOT INCLUDED EXPLICITLY LIKE DATE.H

int main() 
{
    int d,m,y;
    std::cin >> d; //>> std::endl;
    std::cin >> m; //>> std::endl;
    std::cin >> y; //>> std::endl;
    //^ Takes input for the d,m,y

    DateC date(d,m,y);
    //^ Creates an object using the DateC class passing d,m,y into the member variables using the constructor that has parameters 

    std::cout << date.getDay() << "/" << date.getMonth() << "/" << 
    date.getYear() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

date.cpp (file for all the member functions)

```
#include <iostream>
#include "date.h"

//DateC::DateC() {}
//^ using this line the values for d,m,y will be set to 0 which isnt really a suitable default for a date.
//something more reasonable would be 1/1/2015

DateC::DateC(): day(1), month(1), year(2015) {}

DateC::DateC(int d, int m, int y): day(d), month(m), year(y)
{    
   try 
   {
        int day = d;
        if (0<day || day < 32) {
        std::cout << "Valid day" << std::endl;
        }
        else {
            throw (day);
        }
    }
    catch (int Num) {
        std::cout << "Invalid day" << std::endl;
     }
}

int DateC::getDay()
{
    return this->day;
    //this is a pointer to the object that called the getDay() function, in this case date. (check prog.cpp to confirm this)
}

int DateC::getMonth()
{
    return this->month;
    //this is a pointer to the object that called the getMonth() function, in this case date. (check prog.cpp to confirm this)
}

int DateC::getYear()
{
    return this->year;
    //this is a pointer to the object that called the getYear() function, in this case date. (check prog.cpp to confirm this)
}
```

date.h (header file)

```
#ifndef DATEC_H
#define DATEC_H

class DateC {
    private:
        int day, month, year;
    public:
        DateC();
        DateC(int d, int m, int y);
        ~DateC() {};
        int getDay();
        int getMonth();
        int getYear();
        int setDate(int d, int m, int y);
        int printDate();
};

#endif /*DATEC_H*/
```

Note: I haven't implemented all of these functions yet.

So what im struggling with is the error handling of the day(not month and year yet because i'm just seeing if i can error handle the day right now).

I am trying to do the error handling in the date.cpp file using an exception with the condition that if the day is less than 0 or greater than 32 it should be invalid using the conditional:

```
if (0<day || day < 32)
```

This condition seems to let any value for day through but when I change it to

```
if (0<day)
```

it works just fine

so my first question is what am i doing wrong in this conditional.

Then my next question is how would I go about making it so that if an invalid day is entered the program would get the user to enter the date again until they have the correct format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use && operator instead of ||. If you use "or" operator you will always enter the condition. For example if the day is -5, it must be invalid. 0<-5 return false, that is ok, but -5<32 returns true, so result is true.